# scala BufferedSource Position

Tags: scala, inputstream, filereader, fromfile

I have 2 questions about the Scala class `BufferedSource`.

How can I query the current reading position ?

I tried it with `pos` :

```
object testapp extends App {

 val doc = scala.io.Source.fromFile("text.txt")

 println(doc.pos)
 doc.next()
 println(doc.pos)
 doc.next()
 println(doc.pos)
 }
```

Output:

```
 0
 2049
 2050
```

Why it jumps from 0 to 2049 ?!

Is there another way to query the position and/or set it somewhere else ?

Thanks for your help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`pos` returns position of last character returned by `next()`, but the trick is that position is a combination of row and column encoded by position's encoder (`scala.io.Position`) as a single `Integer`:

> The object Position provides convenience methods to encode  *  line
>   and column number in one single integer.  The encoded line  * 
>   (column) numbers range from 0 to `LINE_MASK` (`COLUMN_MASK`),  * 
>   where `0` indicates that the line (column) is undefined and  *  `1`
>   represents the first line (column)...
>
> https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.11.8/src/library/scala/io/Position.scala
>
> http://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.11.8/#scala.io.Source$RelaxedPosition$

Use `Postioner` in order to get more readable info:

> The current input and position, as well as the next character methods
>   delegate to the positioner.

Example:

```
val doc = scala.io.Source.fromFile("aaa.txt")
val positioner =  new doc.Positioner()
val positioned = doc.withPositioning(positioner)
positioned.next()
scala> positioner.cline -> positioner.ccol
res15: (Int, Int) = (1,2)
positioned.next()
scala> positioner.cline -> positioner.ccol
res17: (Int, Int) = (1,3)
```

P.S. `Source` is intended for reading data as stream of characters, so it provides you conveniences like `getLines()` etc, so basically that's why `Positioner` works with rows and columns instead of an absolute position.

If you need an `Iterator` that returns you an absolute position of every character, use `zipWithIndex`:

```
scala> val doc = scala.io.Source.fromFile("aaa.txt").zipWithIndex
doc: Iterator[(Char, Int)] = non-empty iterator

scala> doc.next()
res38: (Char, Int) = (a,0)

scala> doc.next()
res39: (Char, Int) = (a,1)

scala> doc.next()
res40: (Char, Int) = (a,2)

scala> doc.next()
res41: (Char, Int) = (a,3)

scala> doc.next()
res42: (Char, Int) =
(
,4)
```